# How to draw a bar timeline

Tags: python, matplotlib, timeline

I have the type of following data:

```
Begin   End                        Event
 2003  2007                      Event 1
 1991  2016                      Event 2
 2008  2016                      Event 3
 1986  2015                      Event 4
 2013  2013                      Event 5
 1994  1999                      Event 6
 2002  2002                      Event 7
```

My goal is to make a timeline of these events, i.e. to draw a series of distinct straight and horizontal bars from date 1 to date 2 with the names of the events on them.

I am currently trying my luck with the `barh` function from matplotlib.

Comment: See [How to plot a Gantt chart from multiple dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76426207/7758804), which uses this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44519386/7758804) to create a Gantt chart with datetime axis values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there's a need for a special function here. Using `plt.barh` is directly giving you the desired plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

begin = np.array([2003,1991,2008,1986,2013,1994,2002])
end =   np.array([2007,2016,2016,2015,2013,1999,2002])
event = ["Event {}".format(i) for i in range(len(begin))]

plt.barh(range(len(begin)),  end-begin, left=begin)

plt.yticks(range(len(begin)), event)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that Event 4 and 6 seem missing, because start and end are identical. If you want to interprete `end` as being the end of the year, you may add 1 to it,

```
plt.barh(range(len(begin)),  end-begin+1, left=begin)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Made a different serialsation of input data as below, a bit more natural for the incoming data:

```
events = [('Event 0', 2003, 2007),
  ('Event 1', 1991, 2016),
  ('Event 2', 2008, 2016)
  #...
]
```

Also wrapped in a function, as question author may have wanted.

See at https://github.com/epogrebnyak/hrange/blob/master/hrange.py

Comment: This is a link-only answer. The code that answers the question is not incorporated into this answer.